# Image upload ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

Im new to jQuery. I try to upload a jpg image file by using ajax method. But when I upload, it doesn't upload. Could anyone please help me to do this?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    var image=$('#image').val()

        $.post("upload.php",{image:image},function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        });
    }


})
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
     $image=$_POST['image'];

     $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time()."jpg";
     $target_path = "uploads/".$imagename;

     if(move_uploaded_file($image, $target_path)) 
     {
          echo 'moved';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'error';
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To upload file using `ajax` you must need to use `FormData` like below.

```
$("form").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : "upload.php",
        type : "POST", 
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processType : false,
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

And your `PHP` script should be like below.

```
<?php
     $image=$_FILES['image'];
     $image_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

     $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().".jpg";
     $target_path = "uploads/".$imagename;

     if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_path)) 
     {
         echo 'moved';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'error';
     }
?>
```